# Do we really need CSS tag individuality in SFF meta?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, meta

In meta we have a dedicated tag [design](/questions/tagged/design), with the tag wiki:

> For questions regarding the design elements of the main and meta sites e.g. CSS issues

Then why we even need [css](/questions/tagged/css) tag, even designer check [design](/questions/tagged/design) tag only not [css](/questions/tagged/css), so why not make [css](/questions/tagged/css) tag synonym of [design](/questions/tagged/design) tag?

Comment: I don't think this doesn't even need a separate answer; just make [tag:css] a synonym.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is no need for a dedicated [css](/questions/tagged/css) meta tag. CSS is for styling a web page... in other words, for the design of Meta.SciFi. There is nothing the tag can be appropriately used for that is not also covered by [design](/questions/tagged/design), whose description lists:

> For questions regarding the design elements of the main and meta sites **e.g. CSS issues**

Emphasis mine.

The tag should therefore be synonymized with [design](/questions/tagged/design) in the long term (to prevent re-use), but in the short term, could probably be edited out by a 2k+ user from the whopping five questions it's on currently, and it will be deleted at the end of the UTC day.

Comment: what [tag:css] tag?

Comment: @KutuluMike but someone might create it again with HTML too ;)

Comment: @KutuluMike This [meta-tag:css] tag.